# Приватное хранение данных на сервере

Tags: веб-сервер, веб-программирование, сервер, privacy

Приветствую!

Задался я тут вопросом. А как правильно приватно хранить статику, в частности изображения? Мне нравится подход вконтакта: вот, например, ссылка на изображение http://pp.vk.me/c617417/v617417739/1805b/MYtur6kTCKE.jpg - этой ссылкой обладают только те, кому это разрешено логикой сайта, а также те, кому её показали (то есть вы). Вполне рабочий подход - при аплоаде файла генерировать ему случайный длинный путь на сервере и записывать его в базу данных пользователя.

Но в связи с этим возникает вопрос: как гугл (или любой другой поисковик) ищет по сайту? Ну то есть можно вытащить статику из, например, кинопоиска вот таким запросом:  site:st.kp.yandex.net/images/. Но ничего не выйдет, если искать site:pp.vk.me.

Вопрос возник в связи с тем, что нужно реализовать систему приёма решений задач. Решения - фотографии листков и поэтому занимают немало места. В базу данных для каждого пользователя будут вносится прямые ссылки, и он сможет видеть свои решения. Но другие участники не смогут посмотреть его решений, так как у них не будет прямой ссылки.

Чтобы этого добиться, нужно понять, как противодействовать поиску по сайту.

Какие ещё способы найти хранящиеся таким образом файлы на сервере могут возникнуть?

Comment: ВКонтакте, вроде, кто-то писал, меняет эти статические ссылки раз в X дней. Т.е. эта ссылка перестанет работать через какое-то время (по заголовкам судя, после 14-го октября).  Делают это, чтобы не использовали их CDN для хранения статики своего сайта.

Головная страница `pp.vk.me` и `pp.vk.me/robots.txt` отвечают 403-м кодом, значит, поисковики их сразу проигнорируют.

Comment: @Sergiks, http://habrahabr.ru/post/120918/ - c 2011 года все ссылки валидны.

Comment: @G0ohan, спасибо, буду знать! Выходит, вот он, «хороший бесплатный хостинг для картинок вашего сайта!» : )

Answer (score 1):

Бери от имени файла md5 и делай из него url

Answer (score 0):

Простой подход - запретите выдачу индекса по папке с изображениями и запретите поисковикам индексировать ссылки по этому пути.

Запрет индекса папки для веб сервера Apache делается в файле настроек (`httpd.conf` или `.htaccess`):

```
<Directory /images>
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Запрет индексации поисковиками делается с помощью файла `robots.txt`:

```
Disallow: /images
```

Comment: Есть поисковики, которые сознательно игнорируют `robots.txt`

Answer (score 0):

можно пойти путём «[безопасность через неясность (security through obscurity)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)» и генерировать случайное имя файла (как в понравившемся вам подходе), например, с помощью какой-нибудь *hash-функции* (типа *md5*) от его содержимого. если хранить имя файла в секрете, то никто и не сможет получить к нему доступа (если, конечно, для каталога, в котором он находится, внезапно не включён показ содержимого с помощью авто-генерация индексного файла).

а можно воспользоваться, например, механизмом [secure_link http-сервера nginx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/479172/178576), когда, даже зная имя файла и даже обладая ссылкой на файл, его невозможно получить без одновременного совпадения нескольких условий, как то: такой же внешний ip-адрес клиента, такая же строка *user-agent* у браузера, знание секретного слова, неистёкший интервал «жизни» ссылки.