# Защита от выкачиваний видеофайлов с сайта

Tags: php, apache, download

Каким образом можно скрыть прямую ссылку на файл, генерируя временную при запросе видеофайла?

Видел примерно следующее:
`example.com/path/to/video/file.mp4?sessid=A5bGAoBSQ8ADlM%3D:5683f39b:59b18500:`
При запросе по ссылке с сессией, выдается файл на скачивание, при запросе прямого файла (то есть без sessid) внутри контейнера mp4 имеются данные о браузере, IP, путь к файлу без sessid (ведет сюда же), дата генерации и текст "Wrong hash". Так понял ссылка генерируется только при посещении страницы сайта.

Comment: А смысл что-то прятать, ведь если захотят то могу записать видео через Camtasia Studio?

Comment: @sp7 , чтобы избавиться от нежелательных запросов и трафика со стороны, например, когда ссылка вставляется на других сайтах.

Comment: Это обычный mod_rewrite, где mp4 выступает замаскированным php-файлом и который отдает заголовок реального файла, но, прежде чем отдать файл браузеру, файлсервер обращается к сайту с проверкой запроса файла через веб-страницу и, если запрос был, создает сессию по которой можно скачать файл?

Comment: Ну так если вопрос только в трафе , то тем же mod_rewrite и запретите  показ вашего добра на других ресурсах `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp4)$ - [NC,F,L]`

Comment: @redroid Боюсь, защита по рефереру - совсем уж никакая. Самый "надежный" способ - временные ссылки привязанные к IP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

то, что вы видели, реализовано, возможно, с помощью *nginx-овского* механизма *secure_link*.

приведу пример, как это реализовано в одном месте в «моём» хозяйстве.

*php-скрипт*, формирующий ссылку:

```
$file = 'some.file';    // имя файла для скачивания
$timeout = 3600;        // время жизни ссылки в секундах
$address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // ip-адрес клиента
//$address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']; // ip-адрес клиента из другого источника
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; // user-agent
$secret = 'sekred';     // такой же «секрет» прописан на отдающем сервере
$server = 'ser.ver';    // отдающий сервер
//собственно формирование ссылки
$expire = time() + $timeout;
$path   = '/' . $file;
$md5 = base64_encode(md5($secret . $path . $expire . $address . $agent, true));
$md5 = strtr($md5, '+/', '-_');
$md5 = str_replace('=', '', $md5);
//результат — ссылка
$result = "http://" . $server . $path . "?m=" . $md5 . "&e=" . $expire;
```

ссылка получается вида:

```
http://ser.ver/some.file?m=хэш_от_данных&e=время_истечения
```

---

конфигурация *nginx* у отдающего сервера:

```
server {
  listen  80;
  server_name ser.ver;

  location / {
    root /home/files;
    secure_link $arg_m,$arg_e;
    secure_link_md5 "sekred$uri$secure_link_expires$remote_addr$http_user_agent";
    if ($secure_link = "") {
      # ссылка не прошла проверку
      return 301 http://drugoi.ser.ver/haha;
    }
    if ($secure_link = "0") {
      # истекло время
      return 301 http://drugoi.ser.ver/time;
    }
  }
}
```

ключевое здесь — строка `"sekred$uri$secure_link_expires$remote_addr$http_user_agent"`, которая формируется точно так же, как и в скрипте, приведённом выше.

в ней:

- `sekred` — это секретная «добавка», должна совпадать с той, что в скрипте, формирующем ссылку
- `$uri` — подставляется *uri* запрашиваемого файла (`/some.file`)
- `$secure_link_expires` — подставляется время, когда истекает ссылка (оно передаётся параметром `e`)
- `$remote_addr` — подставляется ip-адрес клиента
- `$http_user_agent` — подставляется *user-agent* клиента

---

дополнительная документация:

- http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_secure_link_module.html
- множество примеров можно найти по запросу «nginx secure_link»

Comment: Посмотрел ответ сервера, да, там это реализовано на nginx. Александр, с вашим примером разобрался, только вот не понял как отдающий сервер понимает какой файл у него запрашивают (на скачивание), это `some.file`? Т.е. в вашем примере файл на самом деле хранится в `/home/files/some.file`?

Comment: да – на оба вопроса.

Comment: Александр, nginx'у потребуются еще какие-то настройки, помимо выше приведенных, чтобы работать в качестве файлового сервера? (я никогда с ним не работал)

Comment: для установленного из *debian-овского* репозитория пакета – нет.