# Защита от кражи файлов mp3 с возможностью прослушивания

Tags: php

Всем привет!
На одном из сайтов есть возможность прослушиваний музыки, но сейчас это происходит за счет того, что все лежит в открытом каталоге сайта. Требуется вынести за пределы каталога или закрыть через .htaccess музыкальные файлы.
Однако возникает вопрос как дать возможность прослушивания этой музыки юзеру.
Я пока вижу вариант стриминга чанками. Запуск прослушивания триггерит перенос во временную открытую папку кусок который сейчас прогружен, потом подгружать следующий чанк удаляя предыдущий из временной папки. Защита не 100% но от дурака точно сработает.
В общем вопрос какие у кого есть на этот счет мысли и какие библиотеки на примете. Язык PHP

Comment: дать лишь кусочек на прослушивание....именно не чанками, а просто один фрагмент............ или добавить водяной знак на аудио, как это делают везде....

Comment: Да, сейчас полно расширений, которые качают все, что есть на сайте... С этим сложно бороться.

Comment: [nginx secure_link + временная метка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/479172/330342) (то же самое можно сделать и без настроек nginx)